# Concentration and anti-concentration for norm of random vector with dependent but exchangeable $N(0,1)$-coordinates

Tags: probability, statistics, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$ such that

- **Gaussian marginals**, i.e $X_i$ has distribution $N(0,1)$ for every $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$
- **Exchangeable coordinates**, i.e for every $I \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$, the distribution of the random sub-vector $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is permutation-invariant.

Let, for $k \in 1,2,\ldots$, let $M^{(k)} := \|X\|_2^k$, where $\|X\|_2 := (\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|^2)^{1/2}$.

> **Question.** Are the any concentration and anti-concentration inequalities for the $M^{(k)}$'s ?

I'm particularly interested in the cases $k = 1,2$.

**Note.** By (anti-)concentration inequality, I mean upper (resp. lower) bounds on $\mathbb P(|M^{(k)} - \mathbb E[M^{(k)}]| > \epsilon)$, for every $\epsilon \ge 0$.

Comment: what is anti-concentration

Comment: Inequalities of the form $\mathbb P(|Z - a| > b) \ge c$.

Comment: and $M^{(k)}$ are the statistical moments?

Comment: As defined, $M^{(k)}$ is the euclidean norm of the random vector $X$, raise the result to the power $k$. It is a random variable.

Comment: Are concentration inequalities used at all in information theory or optimal transportation theory do you know of

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the phrasing of your question. If you're asking for places where concentration / anticoncentration inequalities can be learned, take a look at "Concentration inequalities: a nonparametric theory of independence" by Boucheron et al.; "High-dimensional probability" by Vershynin;  "Optimal transport: old and new" by Villani. If your question is about something else, please rephrase.